# Unexpected behavior with d3.svg.line()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to draw a gaussian curve using d3's line function. as follows:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    this.getData();

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    });

  getData() {
    var x,y;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        x = this.normal() // calc random draw from normal dist
        y = this.gaussian(x) // calc prob of rand draw
        let point = {
            "x": x,
            "y": y
        }
        this.data.push(point)
    };
}
```

where `data` is initialized as a class variable like this: `private data;`. The problem is with this line:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    });
```

It gives me an error that says `Property 'x' does not exist on type [number, number]` instead the only properties associated with `d` are `d['0']` and `d['1']`. But I've seen this structure used in many places. Why doesn't it work here? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: if you are climbing the learning curve why do you do this in d3v3? How do you use `this.data`? What is `this.data`?

Comment: Because I'm integrating on a platform that doesn't work well with v4. In between the code blocks I showed that data is a private class variable used to hold the x,y data

Comment: Where do you bind your data? How do you use the line generator `line` for that bound data?

Comment: `push()` is not defined for an `undefined` variable, what does `d` look like **inside** the `line` callbacks? do you want to draw a multi-line with 100000 segments?

Comment: I don't understand the question @altocumulus, but I posted all of the relevant code at this stage I'm using the data generating by getData (). I'm modeling this off of this http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/88cb8a51cdce45f13c7e

Comment: I also tried to set this.data=[]

Comment: Where do you bind your data? How do you use the line generator `line` for that bound data?

Comment: I don't understand your terminology but all of the relevant code is above

Comment: mentioning the blocks in the question would not have turned it into a guessing game, why not post all your code, you obviously do something different then the example, you never mentioned the sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a typing issue, the code the actually written in typescript and for some reason `line ()` was typed to expect a `[number, number]` type. Adding the specifier `line<any>()` cleared up the issue. Like so

```
var line = d3.svg.line<any>()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    });
```